# Simulating read-only public class member using const reference

Tags: c++

I was doing some googling on 'read-only public class members in C++' when I came across the topic of `public const references to private members`:

```
class Planet
{
private:
    int64_t mass_;
public:
    Planet(int64_t mass);

    const int64_t & Mass = mass_;    // I'm using C++11
};
```

I liked this concept better than inline const getter functions because of the syntax sugar: you get to write `myPlanet.Mass` than a rather verbose-looking `myPlanet.GetMass()`. However, I found out that this comes at the cost of memory for one extra reference variable. What I cannot understand is why the compiler does not optimize away the space used by this reference since the object pointed at by it never changes and the object pointed at is known during compile time (thanks to the new c++11 syntax). I tried various optimization settings with gcc, but to no avail.

So I've got 2 doubts:

1. Could there be any reason why the compiler does not optimize away the reference?
2. Is there any way to force the compiler to do this optimization? Maybe using some non-standard `__attribute__` or the new C++11 `[[attribute]]` or something?

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: You pay the cost in memory, and you pay with the inability to set a breakpoint to track access... you gain two less characters per use. Is it worth it?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: People keep bringing up this breakpoint thing in relation to setter/getter functions. I have found these to be remarkably useless. A watchpoint is the only reliable way to watch value changes.

Comment: @ZanLynx: The breakpoint is just the simple tip of the issue. More important considerations (although longer) include that you break encapsulation --you cannot refactor your code to store some other data type and calculate the property and maintain backwards compatibility. This is a higher level design issue: you should not think of accessors to data, but rather of access to properties of the object, which might or not be part of the object. Common example here would be `size()` on a `std::string` or `std::vector`, it could be stored, or calculated but is a property of the container.

Comment: References are not objects -- not only are they not required to have addresses, you can't even get one.  So I think this is just an optimization opportunity your compiler writers haven't gotten to yet.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Unless it is an interface in use by third parties, papering over object changes by changing the implementation of getters and setters is the most performance killing, silly idea that I have ever had the misfortune to run into. Just change the rest of the code. The size() is a big example: if it was calculated as size() was for std::list for a while, people use it without once considering it is a O-squared speed issue.

Comment: @ZanLynx: For a list, `size()` would be linear, not quadratic. And the previous comment still stands, is `std::vector<>::size()` stored or calculated in your implementation? The standard requires constant time, but that does not mean *stored*.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: std::list<>::size() was not required to be constant time until recently. That only happened because people kept using Microsoft's constant time library and assuming the whole world followed. Linear time becomes quadratic when used in a loop as often happened.

Comment: @ZanLynx: `std::vector<>::size()` was always required to be constant time. I am talking specifically about `std::vector<>`, is `size()` stored or calculated in your implementation? What about `std::string::size()`? Does it matter? What matters is that the contract of the `size()` member function guarantees that in both cases the operation is constant time. [BTW, in those loops where the calls to `size()` become O(N*N), access to a member would still be O(N). That is, whether you call it linear vs. constant or quadratic vs. linear, there is a factor of N]

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: If you wish to insist on speaking of vector::size, of course it is constant time. It always was. Now, what happens when a programmer decides that iterator invalidation is ruining his program so he naively changes his data structure from a std::vector to a std::list? In this exact case which I have seen in real life, the abstraction of the STL containers allows a programmer to fall into performance traps *exactly because of interface compatibility*.

Comment: @ZanLynx: I am not sure of whether you are missing the point or intentionally avoiding it. My point is that there are properties of the type that can or not be represented internally as members, and by using an accessor you allow the implementation to decide how it handles it. In the particular case of `std::vector` I have seen implementations where `size()` is not *stored*, but *calculated* out of two pointers (roughly `begin()`, and `end()`). If you provide an accessor by means of a const-reference (whether the space is optimized or not) the property *must* be present in the type.

Answer (score 0):

Compilers only do optimizations that their authors

1. have thought about and
2. considered practically useful to the point of being worth the effort to implement them.

Your approach is unusual enough that probably not 1 and definitely not 2. Getters are simply more flexible and don't have any space cost and all C++ compilers can inline them if they are defined in the class directly (there are cases where they won't be, like when you want to maintain shared library ABI compatibility, but you have full control).